# Сборка VM с HHVM с помощью puphpet

Tags: puppet

Пытаюсь собрать виртуалку на Ubuntu 14.04 с HHVM, но в процессе возникает ошибка, в итоге HHVM так и не устанавливается. Подскажите, как можно исправить.

```
==> project1: Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install hhvm' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> project1: Building dependency tree...
==> project1: Reading state information...
==> project1: The following extra packages will be installed:
==> project1:   ghostscript gsfonts imagemagick-common libboost-context1.54.0
==> project1:   libboost-filesystem1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
==> project1:   libboost-regex1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0
==> project1:   libc-client2007e libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libfftw3-double3 libgd3
==> project1:   libgflags2 libgoogle-glog0 libgs9 libgs9-common libicu52 libijs-0.35
==> project1:   libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjemalloc1 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7
==> project1:   libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libmcrypt4 libmemcached10 libmysqlclient18
==> project1:   libonig2 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpq5 libtbb2 libtiff5 libunwind8 libvpx1
==> project1:   libx11-6 libx11-data libxext6 libxpm4 libxslt1.1 libyaml-0-2 mlock
==> project1:   mysql-common poppler-data
==> project1: Suggested packages:
==> project1:   ghostscript-x hpijs uw-mailutils libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev libgd-tools
==> project1:   fonts-droid libjasper-runtime libmagickcore5-extra libmcrypt-dev mcrypt
==> project1:   poppler-utils fonts-japanese-mincho fonts-ipafont-mincho
==> project1:   fonts-japanese-gothic fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-arphic-ukai
==> project1:   fonts-arphic-uming fonts-unfonts-core
==> project1: The following NEW packages will be installed:
==> project1:   ghostscript gsfonts hhvm imagemagick-common libboost-context1.54.0
==> project1:   libboost-filesystem1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
==> project1:   libboost-regex1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0
==> project1:   libc-client2007e libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libfftw3-double3 libgd3
==> project1:   libgflags2 libgoogle-glog0 libgs9 libgs9-common libicu52 libijs-0.35
==> project1:   libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjemalloc1 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7
==> project1:   libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libmcrypt4 libmemcached10 libmysqlclient18
==> project1:   libonig2 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpq5 libtbb2 libtiff5 libunwind8 libvpx1
==> project1:   libx11-6 libx11-data libxext6 libxpm4 libxslt1.1 libyaml-0-2 mlock
==> project1:   mysql-common poppler-data
==> project1: 0 upgraded, 49 newly installed, 0 to remove and 121 not upgraded.
==> project1: Need to get 42.0 MB of archives.
==> project1: After this operation, 90.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
==> project1: WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
==> project1:   mysql-common
==> project1: E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
==> project1: Error: /Stage[main]/Puphpet::Hhvm::Install/Package[hhvm]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install hhvm' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> project1: Building dependency tree...
==> project1: Reading state information...
==> project1: The following extra packages will be installed:
==> project1:   ghostscript gsfonts imagemagick-common libboost-context1.54.0
==> project1:   libboost-filesystem1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
==> project1:   libboost-regex1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0
==> project1:   libc-client2007e libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libfftw3-double3 libgd3
==> project1:   libgflags2 libgoogle-glog0 libgs9 libgs9-common libicu52 libijs-0.35
==> project1:   libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjemalloc1 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7
==> project1:   libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libmcrypt4 libmemcached10 libmysqlclient18
==> project1:   libonig2 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpq5 libtbb2 libtiff5 libunwind8 libvpx1
==> project1:   libx11-6 libx11-data libxext6 libxpm4 libxslt1.1 libyaml-0-2 mlock
==> project1:   mysql-common poppler-data
==> project1: Suggested packages:
==> project1:   ghostscript-x hpijs uw-mailutils libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev libgd-tools
==> project1:   fonts-droid libjasper-runtime libmagickcore5-extra libmcrypt-dev mcrypt
==> project1:   poppler-utils fonts-japanese-mincho fonts-ipafont-mincho
==> project1:   fonts-japanese-gothic fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-arphic-ukai
==> project1:   fonts-arphic-uming fonts-unfonts-core
==> project1: The following NEW packages will be installed:
==> project1:   ghostscript gsfonts hhvm imagemagick-common libboost-context1.54.0
==> project1:   libboost-filesystem1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
==> project1:   libboost-regex1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0
==> project1:   libc-client2007e libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libfftw3-double3 libgd3
==> project1:   libgflags2 libgoogle-glog0 libgs9 libgs9-common libicu52 libijs-0.35
==> project1:   libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjemalloc1 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7
==> project1:   libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libmcrypt4 libmemcached10 libmysqlclient18
==> project1:   libonig2 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpq5 libtbb2 libtiff5 libunwind8 libvpx1
==> project1:   libx11-6 libx11-data libxext6 libxpm4 libxslt1.1 libyaml-0-2 mlock
==> project1:   mysql-common poppler-data
==> project1: 0 upgraded, 49 newly installed, 0 to remove and 121 not upgraded.
==> project1: Need to get 42.0 MB of archives.
==> project1: After this operation, 90.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
==> project1: WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
==> project1:   mysql-common
==> project1: E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

Config:

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
                box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    vflm_tww6at6129uc:
                        id: project
                        hostname: project.loc
                        network:
                            private_network: 192.168.56.102
                        memory: '2048'
                        cpus: '1'
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
                module_path:
                    - puphpet/puppet/modules
                    - puphpet/puppet/manifests
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_p76jhrcotzr5:
                source: /home/max/Documents/Projects
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
        post_up_message: ''
    ssh:
        host: 'false'
        port: 'false'
        private_key_path: 'false'
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: 'false'
        keep_alive: '1'
        forward_agent: 'false'
        forward_x11: 'false'
        shell: 'bash -l'
        insert_key: 'false'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
    proxy:
        http: ''
        https: ''
        ftp: ''
        no_proxy: ''
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - vim
        - htop
        - git
        - mc
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: en_US.UTF-8
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
        timezone: UTC
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: present
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
        proxy_send_timeout: 600s
        proxy_read_timeout: 600s
        names_hash_bucket_size: 128
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_frozh29xrvt0:
            server_name: project.loc
            www_root: /var/www/project/backend
            listen_port: '80'
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_port: '443'
            ssl_protocols: ''
            ssl_ciphers: ''
            rewrite_to_https: '1'
            spdy: '1'
            locations:
                nxvl_dxqequwaniqc:
                    www_root: ''
                    location: /
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 2.4
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_ndmf2l55apya:
            servername: awesome.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            docroot: /var/www/awesome
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            setenvif:
                - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_qhy9o8e9o5mn:
                    path: /var/www/awesome
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_odnoevqzb6ja:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
letsencrypt:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        email: ''
    domains: {  }
php:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '7.1'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
            - cgi
            - curl
            - memcache
            - memcached
            - mysql
            - mbstring
            - geoip
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_0wuac3bwb0dr:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.21.1
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 8.0.5
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '6'
    npm_packages: {  }
hhvm:
    install: '1'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini:
        hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
        hhvm.server.port: '9000'
        hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
        hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
    php_ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        date.timezone: UTC
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '10.1'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mariadbnu_usf880sleg8r:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mariadbnd_65bshsiir4tt:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mariadbng_0ufsdna7kpn0:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.7'
        root_password: root
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: '1'
    users:
        mysqlnu_9vgf68i0ri4k:
            name: smartprogress
            password: smartprogress
    databases:
        mysqlnd_eam15nc6704x:
            name: project
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_z2ji8ajg5ldd:
            user: smartprogress
            table: 'project.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.4'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
    adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    globals:
        version: 2.6.0
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mailhog:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '8025'
        path: /usr/local/bin/mailhog
beanstalkd:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: '1'
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: 2.3.1
        java_install: true
    instances:
        esi_k2rkpixhzo8z:
            name: es-01
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```